# Help with creating a template for lecture notes

Tags: header-footer, templates, book-design

I'm trying to create a template for my lecture notes, but I really loved the format of one book I bought. I'd love to duplicate that in LaTeX; specifically, the layout, the chapters' heading style, and the page numbering style.

Here's the way I'd like my header to be presented. With the exact same bracket-like symbol:

[image: Here's the way I'd like my header to be presented. With the exact same bracket-like symbol.]

Here's the left header; it has the same bracket-like symbol and the book's name:

[image: Here's the left header; it has the same bracket-like symbol followed by the book's name]

And finally, here's the right header, which has the chapter's name and the page number.
[image: And finally, here's the right header.]

My goal is to duplicate these formats into a template. Since I'm fairly new to LaTeX, I am clueless on how to even start. I hope some of you guys can guide/help me.

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The short answer is that, yes, this is possible *but* I have to warn you that questions of the form "Please di this for me" that show no effort on the part of OP, often don't get answered. You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Hi Andrew! Thanks for the feedback, you are completely right. However, Mr. Jasper Habicht was an incredibly kind person and posted a working example down below. I could not appreciate it more, many thanks Mr. Habicht!!! I wish I could become as proficient in LaTeX as you are!

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at packages like `geometry`, `titlesec` and `fancyhdr`. Maybe, before you create a real template, you should test with a regular tex file. As for the fonts, you may want to use XeLaTeX that allows you to use whatever font installed on your system.

Maybe start with the following:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[headheight=18pt,
 inner margin=35mm,
 outer margin=40mm]{geometry}

\newcommand{\thehook}{%
 \hspace{.5em}%
 \setlength{\unitlength}{1em}%
 \raisebox{-.5em}{\begin{picture}(.4,1.7)
  \put(0,0){\line(1,0){.2}}
  \put(.2,0){\line(0,1){1.7}}
  \put(.2,1.7){\line(1,0){.2}}
 \end{picture}}%
 \hspace{.5em}%
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[RO]{\sffamily\rightmark\thehook\textbf{\thepage}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\sffamily\textbf{\thepage}\thehook\rightmark}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
 \fancyhf{}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\sffamily}{\bfseries\thechapter}{0pt}{\thicklines\thehook}[\vspace{2em}]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Tools of the Trade}

\lipsum[1-5] 

\end{document}
```